# Understanding ffmpeg input stream information

Tags: video, ffmpeg, usb

When running `ffmpeg` I get the following input/output/stream statements. I need to understand the details here.

```
$ ffmpeg -y -nostdin -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -c:v mjpeg -i /dev/video1 -c:v copy /tmp/v1.mov

Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video1':
  Duration: N/A, start: 762195.237801, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080, -5 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc

Output #0, mov, to '/tmp/v1.mov':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (jpeg / 0x6765706A), yuvj422p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, -5 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc

Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
frame= 1685 fps= 30 q=-1.0 Lsize=  212483kB time=00:00:56.08 bitrate=31036.6kbits/s
```

I want to connect 2 USB cameras over a USB 3.0 hub. My cameras are USB 2.0 cameras. Running 2 cameras at low resolution or framerate works, but at high resolution/framerate, I run out of USB bandwidth.

> Does `Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown)` means that
>   ffmpeg is receiving **both** the compresses mjpeg stream **and** and
>   uncompressed yuv stream? If this is the case it explains the bandwidth
>   issue. I ask because I can see that the compressed bitrate is only 31 Mbit in the Stream mapping section.
>
> My question would then become, can I force the camera to **only**
>   stream the compressed mjpeg stream?

*p.s. I know I can plug the cameras into separate USB ports, but I only have 3 ports and need to record 6 cameras, so I need at least 2 cameras per USB (3.0) hub.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown)`,  `mjpeg` is the codec, `yuvj422p` is the pixel format of the uncompressed stream that ffmpeg will decode the input to, `pc` indicates that the entire bit depth is used to signal color i.e. 0 = black and 255 = white. The next three values indicate the color space properties. I believe the order is primaries, space, and transfer characteristics (or gamma function).

So, you are not ingesting two streams at once.

Comment: My experiments show that the order seems to be: space, primaries and transfer characteristics.